# Is it possible to check when an image data attribute is displayed?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I dont want to know if that data attribute is there, I need to know when it is displayed. I have a gif loader that I want to hide once that data attribute is done loading and displayed.

```
function imageLoader(){
    var gifLoader = document.getElementById("image-loader");
    var show = function(){
        gifLoader.style.display = "block";
        setTimeout(hide, 1000);
    }
    var hide = function(){
        gifLoader.style.display = "none";
    }
    show();
}
```

here is my current working code, but i do not want to use a timeout. I just want to hide it when the data attribute is displayed to the screen.

here is my data attr

```
<img class="imageresource" src="<%= images.main %>" data-img-zoom="<%= images.full %>" alt="<%- post_title %>">

<div id="image-loader"></div>
<canvas id="mycanvas" class="imagepreview" src=""></canvas>
```

my canvas code

```
        function drawImage(image) {
        var mycanvas = document.getElementById('mycanvas');
        imgTouchObj = new ImgTouchCanvas({
            canvas: mycanvas,
            path: image.data('imgZoom')
        });
    }
```

Comment: `data-*` attributes aren't *displayed*, nor do they spend any time loading such that you'd have to wait for it to be "done loading". Can you explain a bit more clearly what your goal is?

Comment: Agree with comment above.  Not sure what you mean by "when the data attribute is displayed ".

Comment: Well i am "displaying" it to a canvas element, but i do not know how to detect when that is done happening. @T.J.Crowder if that makes sense.

Comment: I updated with where i draw to the canvas. hope that helps